# Livestream no longer working on Black Ops 2 on PS3

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-black-ops-2, streaming

My livestream on Black Ops 2 for PS3 is no longer working. I tried to livestream, it allowed me to for short periods of time for like two days. Now whenever I try to, it doesn't let me at all. Both my Youtube and Twitch accounts are connected, I've tried streaming on League Play and Public match, I've reset my router and PS3, I have the correct MBPS speed to be able to livestream (I have checked via SpeedTest)... Nothing will work! It let me before perfectly fine but now the "ON | OFF" switch doesn't do anything, it won't even turn on and give me an error, it just doesn't move, as if none of my accounts are connected. Speaking of, I have unlinked and reconnected them, too! It's quite irritating since it was just working the other day.

People have said it might be because so many people are on... or you have to have a certain number of subscribers on Youtube, etc. That isn't a problem. I've got 100+ subscribers on my Youtube, and like I said I have streamed before about 2 weeks ago with no problem! I don't know what to do and I just wanna stream. :( If anyone can help or has any suggestions, please let me know!